# Basic trig: math.atan() issue

Tags: python, trigonometry

I'm having a little trouble with some basic trig. I'm doing some math homework, and I finally got bored of converting rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates and vice versa, so I decided to whip up a little Python program to help me with the conversions. However, Math.atan() is giving me a little trouble. Here's the code:

```
def rect_to_polar_input(x, y):
    hypotenuse = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))
    tangent = float(y / x);
    angle = round(math.degrees(math.atan(tangent)));

    if x <= 0:
        if(y >=0):
            angle += 90

        if(y <= 0):
            angle+= 180

    if x >= 0:
        if(y<0):
            angle+=270

    return hypotenuse, angle
```

In case you're wondering why I have those clunky `if` statements in there, it's to add the correct angle for the quadrant the rectangular coordinates are in. Quadrant 2 is 90 degrees away from Quadrant 1, and Quadrant 3 is 180 degrees from Quadrant 1, etc.

Now, if I enter a value like `(5, 5)`, everything works as expected. However, if I enter `(-5, 5)`, I get a value of `7.07, 45`, where I should be getting `7.07, 135`. If I enter `(-5, -5)`, I get a value of `7.07, 225`, which is expected. Finally, if I enter a value of `(5, -5)`, I still get a value of `7.07, 225`. I've tried everything I can think of, but it's not working. So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `atan2` for this. It deals with the quadrants exactly as you need. Like so:

```
def rect_to_polar_input(x, y):
    hypotenuse = math.hypot(x, y)
    angle = round(math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x)))
    if angle<0:
        angle += 360
    return hypotenuse, angle
```

The `if` statement is to deal with the fact that you want results in the range 0..360, but `atan2` gives angles in the range -180..180.

You can do this with `atan` using the basic approach you have taken, but you've not quite debugged it yet. In any case, everybody uses `atan2` for this.

Also, you may as well use `hypot` rather than rolling your own.