# Python parse mathematical text expression

Tags: python, regex, math, eval

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good python library for evaluation text-based mathematical expressions. So for example,

```
>>> evaluate("Three plus nine")
12

>>> evaluate("Eight + two")
10
```

I've seen similar examples that people have done for numeric values and operators in a string. [One method used `eval` to compute the literal value of the expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685946/math-operations-from-string). And [another method of doing this used regex to parse the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string).

If there isn't an existing library that handles this well I will probably end up using a combination of the regex and eval techniques for this. I just want to confirm that there isn't already something like this already out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), which does general recursive descent parsing. In fact, [here](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py/30154950/fourFn.py) is something quite close to your second example.

About your other suggestions.

- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe) about the security issues of eval (ironically, using it for a calculator).
- Fundamentally, [regular languages are weaker than pushdown automata languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). You shouldn't try to fight a general parse tree problem with regexes.

Comment: Some good advice there in the note about not relying on regex. Thank you.