# Decimal/Fraction input issue

Tags: python, decimal

I'm attempting to get a user input as a fraction but use it as a decimal, in python

For example:

```
chance = input("Enter chance")
```

Let's assume the user enters "3/4"

How can I convert "3/4" to "0.75" for further calculations, such as:

```
total = chance + 36/67  # Where total is a float value
```

P.S. I'm new to python so if this seems a bad question I apologise but I couldnt find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math operations from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685946/math-operations-from-string)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? In Python 2 you will need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: @NormanPercy not a duplicate as answers to that question involve eval(), leading to security issues

Comment: @AlexHall python 3 so no raw_input required

Comment: While eval can be dangerous, the question doesn't explicitly state _not_ to use eval(), and there are alternatives listed in the other thread as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you've handled getting the user to input text.  Then convert that text to a `fractions.Fraction`

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction("3/4")
Fraction(3, 4)
```

You have various options from there.  You could continue to use it as a `Fraction` but if you insist on using values of type `float` then simply convert to a float

```
>>> float(fractions.Fraction("3/4"))
0.75
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the input format and convert to numerator/denominator as needed before performing the necessary math operation to convert it from a fraction to a decimal value.

```
chance = "3/4"

# verify that format is valid, then proceed to conversion
tokens = chance.split("/")
numer = int(tokens[0])
denom = int(tokens[1])
value = numer / denom
print(value)
```

If you're using an older version of python (eg 2.x) you will need to convert one of the parts to a float because python discards floating point during int/int division.

Comment: In addition to what Alex said: The note on the older python version (2.x) is wrong. Python never converts floats to ints. Also `/` is not an integer division.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann In python 2, `3 / 4 ` returns 0, instead of 0.75 as it does in python 3.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann "3/4 + 1" is also not valid input as far as I'm concerned and should crash in the  validation step.

Comment: Using python 3, this answer works perfectly fine for my purposes