# How to solve an equation in Python 3 with Sympy?

Tags: python-3.x, math, sympy, equation-solving

I new with Python and much more with Sympy, I'm trying to solve an equation; the user introduces the equation and the value of 'x'. Example: eq: x**2+x*3+1, x = 4, so the 4 should be replaced on the 'x' of the equation and calculate the result.

This is what I have been trying:

```
import sympy
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy.core.function import Derivative
from sympy.core.relational import Eq
from sympy.core.symbol import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')

info = input("Introduce the equation and the value of /'x' \nEg: x**3+x**2+1 9\n")

infoList = info.split()

equation = infoList[0]
x_value = infoList[1]

expr = equation
eqResult = expr.subs(x, x_value)

print(eqResult)
```

The error is that the `expr`, which is an str object, has no attribute `subs`.
Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The function `eval()` works fine, but is there a solution less risky?
I have been doing other stuff and tried to calculate the Derivative of the function:

```
x = Symbol('x')

info = input("Introduce the equation and the value of /'x' \nEg: x**3+x**2+1 9\n")

infoList = info.split()

equation = infoList[0]
x_value = infoList[1]

exprDerivada = Derivative(equation, x)
resultDerivate = exprDerivada.doit().subs({x:x_value})
```

The code above gives the result of the first derivate of a function, but the equation is accepted as it comes without the function: `eval()`

Again, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a string object that indeed doesn't have a `subs` property
Use `eval(expr).subs(.....)` to convert the string to the math expression.
However `eval()` is a risky stuff to use as it will execute pretty much anything. So be sure to properly secure the user input or you could get you system destroyed by malicious user input. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686074/4350650) answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Mayeul_sgc Ok I get it, so is there a less risky solution? Also, I have been doing other operations: I tried to calculate the derivative of a function using the same input method and it doesn't need the function ```eval()```, works fine with this: ```Derivative(equation, x)```, I have update the question, anyway your answer is what I need.

Comment: You could use `simpleeval` package but i never used it myself. If the answer answers your question don't hesitate to mark as solved

Comment: You can use sympy's `parse_expr` function.