# Django input field

Tags: python, django

I am making a project in Django which takes an equation having some variables and then perform mathematical function on it using python.

Right now, I have CharField as an input field for entering equation but the problem is that it returns string which I can't use for calculation purpose.

For eg. The user inputs an equation $x^2 + $y^2. Now I want to substitute value of x and y but the equation is in the form of string and I cannot calculate the value.

So, is there any input field in Django which can take equation in a particular form so that I can input value in those variables?

Comment: You can substitute your variables and use eval() on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686074/4151233

Comment: Note that `eval()` can be very dangerous in terms of security.

Comment: @meni181818 Okay! So, can you suggest any other method?

Comment: @Arnav share what logic/library you are using to process the equation.

Comment: @meni181818 I am making a function that takes user-input Equation from Django form and then I am calling that function in the matplotlib 3D library as the 3rd argument for plotting the 3D graph.

Comment: @Arnav so maby with 2 fields, first for `x`, and second for `y`